# How can you get fire/cold resistance in WazHack?

Tags: wazhack

In [Wazhack](http://www.wazhack.com/) cold resistance is pretty damn useful as being frozen by a winter wolf can be a death sentence, not to mention annoying. Fire resistance is also very, very useful.

You can sometimes get fire resistance by eating Hellhound remains.
You can sometimes get cold resistance by eating Winter Wolf remains.
There is also a ring of fire resistance.

Is there any other way to get fire/cold resistance, especially cold resistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that also eating brown molds can give you cold resistance, very handy.

Comment: Positive effect seems to correlate to  seeing the message "you feel full of hot air"

Comment: Have found it best to keep the blob of brown mold goo until its status is "old" - fresh never seems to work

Answer (score 1):

There is a potion of fireproofing. Not sure if you can quaff it and become inherently fireproof, but pour it on a hat or cape and it seems to work to good effect. The message will run something like "your feathered cap looks moist". Also good on a bag of swag. Then in the midst of a gang attack of monsters may ye read the blessed scroll of fire with impunity. Well, assuming you fireproof your scrolls or keep them in the fireproof bag.

Have also noticed that when you eat a blob of goo from an acid blob, it will sometimes (p~0.1?) cause the message "you feel a momentary chill", which may relate to subsequently observed fire resistance.